# LibreOffice Calc: Substitute number with another number, but only inside a function?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a row of numbers that looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to have a function that will SUM all the cells from B2:F2 and show them in G2, but function should replace all occurrences of number 1 and replace them with number 12. So that when someone is looking at the table he sees number 1, but function should internally use 12 instead of 1 for its calculations. I should get 48 in G2.

How could I achieve this in LibreOffice Calc?
Is it possible to place multiple *"variables"* that would get replaced with different numbers during calculation? Lets say I would like to replace occurrences of 1, 2 and X, with number 12?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For first case formula can be like as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2:F2=1;12;B2:F2))
```

It's simple: *"If cell value in B2:F2 is equal 1 then calculate it as 12 else as value from B2:F2"*

For second case you can use CHOOSE() function or (it's better) LOOKUP() function

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(LOOKUP(B2:F2;{1;2;<your X>};{12;12;12});B2:F2))
```